# Under what conditions product of two matrices gives a identity matrix.

Tags: matrices

Under what conditions product of a matrix $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{l\times m}$ with a sparse matrix $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times l}$ gives a identity matrix $\mathbf{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{l\times l}$.

Comment: Do you mean BA or AB?

Comment: @Bernard BA I believe, since C is l by l.